# How can I read a file from the command line using scanner

Tags: java

It wont prompt the user to enter file? Please help me

```
public static void main (String args []){
if (0 < args.length) { 
     File inFile = new File(args[0]); // Make sure the file exists, can read, etc...
     while (!inFile.exists()) {
      Scanner console = new Scanner (inFile);
      System.out.println ("Input file:"); //prompt user to input file
         String inFileName = console.nextLine();
         System.out.println ("Input file:"); //prompt user to input file
         inFileName =inFileName.trim(); //get rid of whitespace
           System.out.println(inFileName);
         inFile = new File (inFileName);
      }
```

Comment: You're confusing what args[] actually is. `String args[]` refers to the program arguments that you can give to the main method.

Answer (score 1):

The old way :

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( System.in)); String userInput = reader.readLine();
```

The new way :

```
Console console = System.console(); 
if( console != null) { String userInput = console.readLine();
```

Comment: I wish I could use the BufferedReader, but I can't for class, thanks anyway :)

Comment: Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); You can then call get values using one of the various scanner.getXXX() methods depending on the type of value you require from the user.

Comment: I tried that inside and outside of while loop, still didn't prompt for any input?

Answer (score 1):

For Scanner you need to use.

```
Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can do the expected task with few lines of code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Input file : ");
        String inFile = userInput.next();
        System.out.println("Input file is " + inFile);
    }
```